# Code stores a vector as a vector<vector>, why no error message?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on a piece of C++ code left by a predecessor, and it apparently stores a `vector<long int>` as a `vector<vector<long int>>`. The code compiles and runs, but I don't understand why. Here's the function that does the storing.

```
void setPotentialParameters(const int& seed, const int& nMax, const double& lambdaStd, const int fieldNum, potentialPars& par)
{
    gsl_rng * r = gsl_rng_alloc (gsl_rng_taus);
    gsl_rng_set (r, seed);
    par.nMaximum= nMax;
    par.fNum= fieldNum;
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) gsl_ran_gaussian (r, lambdaStd);
    int counter=0;
    vector<long int> tempNs(fieldNum); //Defines tempNs as a vector<long int>
    for (long int i=0; i< (-0.2+pow(2*nMax+1, fieldNum)); i++) { 
        findPartition(i, fieldNum, 2*nMax+1, tempNs ); 
        for (int i = 0; i < tempNs.size(); i++) {
            tempNs[i] -= nMax;
        }
        if (goodPartition(tempNs, nMax)) {
            counter++;
            par.lambdas.push_back(abs( gsl_ran_gaussian (r, lambdaStd))); 
            par.nVals.push_back(tempNs); //Stores tempNs in nVals
            par.alphas.push_back(2*M_PI * gsl_rng_uniform (r));
        };
    };
};
```

And this is the struct that tempNs is stored in.

```
struct potentialPars{
    int nMaximum;
    int fNum;
    vector<double> lambdas;
    vector<vector<long int> >  nVals; //Defines nVals as a vector<vector<long int>>
    vector<double> alphas;
};
```

I marked the three most relevant lines with comments. tempNs only has one element (as seen from the `tempNs[i] -= nMax` line), consistent with its definition as a `vector<long int>` but when nVals is called elsewhere in the program it has two elements, also consistent with its definition as a `vector<vector<long int>>`. It doesn't seem possible. Even though tempNs is modified by the findPartition function, it should still remain a vector of long integers. What am I missing?

Comment: use comments in code and not * before code, as * is having some meaning in c++

Comment: Not *as*, but *in*. You can have a bag which contains other bags.

Comment: `tempNs` is not the same object as `nVals`. `nVals`'s elements are copies of `tempN`.

Comment: A `vector<vector<long> >` has elements of type `vector<long>`.   A vector's `push_back()` method copies an element to the vector.  `par.nValues` is of type `vector<vector<long> >` so pushing `tempNS` - which is of type `vector<long>` is completely appropriate.

Comment: `vector<vector<long int> >  nVals;` <-- it is *defined* to accept vectors. The code puts vectors into it using `nVals.push_back(tempN)`. `tempN` is a vector.

Comment: Thanks for answers, it makes sense now. To confirm: suppose tempNs[5] = 2, and it is the third vector that's stored in nVals. Does this mean that nVals [3][5] = 2?

Comment: No, it means `nVals[2][5] = 2`.  The first element of a vector is index zero, not one.

Comment: @Peter suggest writing that as an answer, since it solves my question =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `vector<vector<long> >` has elements of type `vector<long>`.

A `vector`s `push_back()` method copies an element to the vector.

In code you've shown, `par.nValues` is of type `vector<vector<long> >` so pushing `tempNS` - which is of type `vector<long>` - is completely appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in using a vector of vectors of longs.
Its almost the same as using a two-dimensional array, but you don't need to know the size at compile time or manage memory allocation.

There is no problem for compiling that code. Vector elements can be primitives(int, float, double), pointers or other objects(like vector or your user-defined classes).

Answer (score 1):

The constraints on the (first) type parameter of `std::vector` are fairly lax. Almost any non-reference type can be stored in a `std::vector`, including `std::vector`s of something else. This is exactly what this code is doing.

You could wrap `std::vector<long int>` in a

```
struct partition { 
    std::vector<long int> indexes; 
    double lambda; 
    double alpha; 
};
```

and change `potentialPars` to

```
struct potentialPartitions {
    int nMaximum;
    int fNum;
    std::vector<partition> partitions;
};
```

which would add clarity, but would change how the consumer of `potentialPartitions` accesses those values.